# Как указать в генераторе списка несколько операций?

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

К примеру есть код:

```
n = 0
for a in index:
    # Операция №1
    term_list.insert(n,term[a])
    # Операция №2
    n += 1
```

И есть еще один код (генератор списка):

```
n = 0                      # Операция №1
term_list_Search = [term_list.insert(n,term[a]) for a in index]
```

По сути могут быть идентичны. Только вот как добавить во второй код, `Операция №2`, то есть 2 действия вместо одного?

Код целиком:

```
while True:
    term = input('| Введите выжарение: ')
    long_term = len(term)
    
    # В списке index хранится все индексы символов введеных пользователем
    index = []
    # Получаем индекс каждого введеного пользователем символа
    if long_term > 0:
        while long_term > 0:
            long_term = long_term - 1
            index.insert(0,long_term)
            print('| ',index)
    elif long_term == 0: 
        print('| Ошибка! Поле ввода пусто', '\n|')
        continue
    
    # В списке term_list хранятся все элементы строки введеной пользователем
    term_list = []
    # Записываем в список term_list все элементы строки введеной пользователем
    
    print('|\n|')
    n = 0
    for a in index:
        term_list.insert(n,term[a])
        n += 1
        print('| ',term_list)
```

Пример работы скрипта:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: можете привести небольшой пример входных данных и ожидаемый результат? Из вопроса неясно содержит ли список `term_list` элементы до начала работы цикла - уточните пожалуйста.  Иногда приходится слегка менять логику алгоритма при переписывании обычного цикла списковым включением

Comment: @MaxU Выложил код полностью, `term_list` до начала списка пуст

Comment: лучше бы вы привели примеры входных и выходных данных

Comment: @MaxU Привел пример входных и выходных данных

Comment: @АнатолийМихеенко _Привел пример входных и выходных данных_, а где вы их   добавили, почему их не видно в вопросе?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

если я правильно понял логику вашего кода, то это можно сделать гораздо проще и понятнее:

```
term_list = [term[i] for i in index]
```

PS `list.insert()` - возвращает `None`, поэтому его не стоит использовать в списковых включениях, если не хотите получить список `None`s

#### NOTE: примеры входных и выходных данных явно улучшили бы качество и понимание вопроса!

Comment: Вы правильно поняли логику кода, использование `list.insert()` было обусловлено тем, что я не был до конца уверен, в каком порядке получится содержимое списка, по тому решил сделать этот процесс управляемым